# visual studio code java folder structure

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use Visual Studio Code to work in a Java project with the following folder structure:

[Folder Structure in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsOqt.png)

I find it really annoying that every empty folder is displayed. I would like VS Code to recognize the empty folders and merge them to display only one path.

[Example Image of merged Folder Structure in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49RAX.png)

Is it possible to configure VS Code to 'merge' the empty folders like it is done in eclipse?

Comment: For anyone interested in this feature - they are already working on it and planning releasing it very soon. [There is the original issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41627)